# Android SQLiteDatabase Column doesn't exist

Tags: android, sqlite

So I'm making a database for my Android app using SQLite and for some reason it thinks my column "START_DATE_COLUMN" doesn't exist (my log statement returns -1 for the column index). This is weird because when I looked at the .db file in a SQLite browser the column is there with all of the entries I added.

Here's the code for my DatabaseHelper class:

```
import android.content.ContentValues;
import android.content.Context;
import android.database.Cursor;
import android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase;
import android.database.sqlite.SQLiteOpenHelper;
import android.provider.BaseColumns;
import android.util.Log;

public class DatabaseHelper extends SQLiteOpenHelper implements BaseColumns {

public static final int DATABASE_VERSION = 3;
public static final String DATABASE_NAME = "JobEntries.db";
public static final String TABLE_NAME = "jobs";
public static final String NAME_COLUMN = "name";
public static final String START_DATE_COLUMN = "startDate";

private static final String SQL_CREATE_ENTRIES = "CREATE TABLE " + TABLE_NAME + " " +
        "(" + _ID + " INTEGER PRIMARY KEY, "
        + NAME_COLUMN
        + " TEXT, "
        + START_DATE_COLUMN
        + " TEXT)";
private static final String SQL_DELETE_ENTRIES = "DROP TABLE IF EXISTS " + TABLE_NAME;

public DatabaseHelper(Context context){
   super(context,DATABASE_NAME,null,DATABASE_VERSION);
}

@Override
public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db) {
    db.execSQL(SQL_CREATE_ENTRIES);
}

@Override
public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase db, int oldVersion, int newVersion) {
    db.execSQL(SQL_DELETE_ENTRIES);
    onCreate(db);
}

public boolean insertJob(JobEntry job){
    SQLiteDatabase db = this.getWritableDatabase();
    ContentValues contentValues = new ContentValues();
    contentValues.put(this.NAME_COLUMN, job.getClientName());
    contentValues.put(this.START_DATE_COLUMN, job.getStartDate());
    db.insert(this.TABLE_NAME,null,contentValues);
    return true;
}

public Cursor getDataByDate(String startDate){
    SQLiteDatabase db = this.getReadableDatabase();
    Cursor result = db.rawQuery("SELECT " + NAME_COLUMN + " FROM " +TABLE_NAME+" WHERE " +START_DATE_COLUMN+ " =" +startDate+"",null);
    result.moveToFirst();
    Log.d("Column Index ", Integer.toString(result.getColumnIndex(START_DATE_COLUMN)));
    return result;
}
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`startDate` is a TEXT

try to add a single quote **'** to your query whereArgs and add the `START_DATE_COLUMN` to your selected column like:

```
Cursor result = db.rawQuery("SELECT " + NAME_COLUMN + ", " + START_DATE_COLUMN + " FROM " +TABLE_NAME+" WHERE " +START_DATE_COLUMN+ " = '" +startDate+ "' ",null);
```

or

```
Cursor result = db.query(TABLE_NAME, new String[] { NAME_COLUMN, START_DATE_COLUMN }, START_DATE_COLUMN + " = ? ", new String[] { startDate }, null, null, null );
```

Answer (score -1):

Is this the log statement you are referencing?

```
Log.d("Column Index ", Integer.toString(result.getColumnIndex(START_DATE_COLUMN)));
```

If so, it returns -1 because you aren't selecting START_DATE_COLUMN in the SELECT statement that you built earlier in the method.  This would be one way to modify the SELECT statement to include that column:

```
Cursor result = db.rawQuery("SELECT " + NAME_COLUMN + ", " + START_DATE_COLUMN + " FROM " +TABLE_NAME+" WHERE " +START_DATE_COLUMN+ " =" +startDate+"",null);
```

Answer (score -1):

This `db.rawQuery("SELECT " + NAME_COLUMN + " FROM " +TABLE_NAME+" WHERE " +START_DATE_COLUMN+ " =" +startDate+"",null);` will produce results like this. You get -1 because you only query data from NAME_COLUMN,

```
+-------------------+
|       name        |
+-------------------+
| Android Developer |
| Python Developer  |
| Django Developer  |
+-------------------+
```

If you also want to include START_DATE_COLUMN, then we can change the query to `"SELECT * FROM " +TABLE_NAME+" WHERE " + START_DATE_COLUMN + " =" +startDate+""` or `"SELECT " + NAME_COLUMN + ", " + START_DATE_COLUMN + " FROM " +TABLE_NAME+" WHERE " +START_DATE_COLUMN+ " =" +startDate+""` which will produce:

```
+-------------------+--------------+
|       Name        |  startDate   |
+-------------------+--------------+
| Android Developer | October 16th |
| Python Developer  | October 17th |
| Django Developer  | October 18th |
+-------------------+--------------+
```

Now, `Integer.toString(result.getColumnIndex(START_DATE_COLUMN))` won't return -1.